# ExcelDataReader not reading the xls file in some cases

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xls, exceldatareader

When using excelDatareader for some Excel file the `ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream)` is returning null and not taking the filestream. But for some  excel file it is running perfect.

Can somebody explain me the reason?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FileStream stream = File.Open(@"C:\Users\nichi-user\Desktop\BLRJCCI.xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);

    DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

    result.Tables[0].TableName.ToString();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Excel can be of two types:
-Binary (MS Excel 2003 and older versions - .xls)
-Zip - based on Open Office XML standards (MS Excel 2007 onwards - .xlsx)

You should try to use following for older excel format files:

ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fileStream);

Answer (score 3):

ExcelDataReader can in most cases detect what type of file it is if you use ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader instead. See https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader for supported formats and versions.